# What does the "Storage Account" setting of an Azure Function App do?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

It has a default selection of "functionb7be452dbab0" in my case, but I can change it to select other **storage accounts**. There is no documentation that I can see which explains the `storage account` setting.

Comment: Did you find the answer of you question?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is used for several things:

In Consumption mode, it holds your files, using Azure Files. i.e. all you function files exist in there.

In addition, the script runtime (based on the WebJobs SDK) uses Blobs, Queues and Tables as part of its infrastructure. e.g. it uses that to synchronize the work between multiple instances. It also stores logging information there.

Note that you can easily see all this by using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and looking at all the things in there.

As an aside, you can optionally also make use of this storage account for your own queues and blobs that you want to use in your functions.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your "as an aside", is there any advantage to using that newly created storage account for queues and blobs? Like performance?

Comment: There is no perf advantage of using it instead of a different storage account. The only benefit is to avoid the need to use an additional account, but that's a fairly marginal benefit.

Comment: Hope I'm not too late. It seems we have access, from Function code, to the Files share within that Storage. Can we also mount that Files share from some cloud/on-premise machine, like you would do with any "normal" share? TA

Comment: @superjos [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) has info on mounting Azurfe File shares. Not that this is general and not specific to Azure functions.

Comment: Can we use same storage account for two function app? what is the Best practice ? One SA or Different storage account for each function app?

Comment: @samash yes, you can use the same storage account for multiple function apps (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations#shared-storage-accounts)).

Comment: If you use the same storage account for multiple function apps, be sure that the function apps have names of 32 characters or less. Function apps with names longer than 32 characters will run (with a warning) but this is one place where they cause issue. If two function apps sharing a storage account have the same first 32 characters in their names you get some awful behavior as they look at each other's storage accounts.